# How to exclude some rows from a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need help to exclude some rows:
I would like for example to exclude three patients from my analysis (patients 1, 2, 6)
Can you tell me why this code doesn't work and what I should write?

```
baseline_all_patients=baseline[baseline["studyid"]!=(1, 2, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
mask_patient = (~baseline["studyid"].isin([1, 2, 6]))
baseline_all_patients = baseline[mask_patient]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues with the thing you tried:

1. lists use square brackets
2. you want the studyids not IN the list, rather than equal to the list.

I think this does what you're trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd
baseline = pd.DataFrame({'studyid':range(10),'info':range(100,90,-1)})
baseline[~baseline.studyid.isin([1,2,6])]
```